# How to show a customize page in Shopify that fetch and show specific dynamic data based on user input

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to have a page in my **Shopify** store, where users can **upload** an "image or voice" and I send it to another 3rd party API, which does some changes to the image or voice and get some result. So then I can use Printful to print the resulting picture on some stuff. The thing is that my resulting picture is coming from a 3rd party API **based on user input** (dynamic images like a QRCode for example).

*user input -> process in 3rd-API -> result image -> user confirm the output -> pass image to printful -> printful process ...*

[image]

In brief, I want to fetch data to a third-party API, based on user input. How should I **implement** it? What should I use in order to implement it? How can I call an API and show the result on the Shopify page?

Comment: Can you be more specific, e.g. what the exact problem is? From what I can see, you have answered how to do it and your question asks for a confirmation which is - yes.

Comment: @TwistedOwl I added some extra details in my question. Is it clear now?